# jsPlumb container is not scrolling when moving objects to the top or left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

Im using jsPlumb, Im facing the problem that when I drag an object to the top of the container or to the left the scroll bar are nut showing but the object will be invisible, otherwise when dragging the object down or to the right the scroll bar is appearing and im being able to scroll to see the objects, is there a workaround to solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: Are you using `jsPlumb.draggable()` to make element draggable?

Comment: @user2964819 Found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making use of `jsPlumb.draggable()` I would recommend you to extend jQuery draggable and include the **[scroll](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll)** option for your requirement.

```
$('#elementId').draggable(
{
    scroll:true,
    drag: function(){
        jsPlumb.repaint($(this)); // To repaint the connections and endpoints when element is dragged
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/212

This GitHub issue doesn't exactly solve the issue, but you can restrict your draggables from going to top or left.

in draggable options, add this:

```
{
    getConstrainingRectangle: () => [99999, 99999],
    containment: true,
}
```